# Difference between Two Queries - Join vs IN

Tags: sql

I have the following two queries. Query1 is returning 1000 as row count where as Query2 is returning 4000 as row count. Can someone please explain the difference between both the queries. I was hoping both would return same count.

**Query1:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TableA A 
WHERE A.VIN IN (
    SELECT VIN 
    FROM TableB B, TableC C
    WHERE B.MODEL_YEAR = '2014' AND B.VIN_NBR = C.VIN
)
```

**Query2:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLEA A, TableB B, TableC C
WHERE B.MODEL_YEAR = '2014' AND B.VIN_NBR = C.VIN AND A.VIN = C.VIN
```

Comment: one is likely returning multiple rows for a.vin

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, they will return the same answer, but not necessarily.  The first counts the number of rows in A that match the conditions -- each row is counted only once, regardless of the number of matches.  The second does a `join`, which can multiply the number of rows.

The second query would be equivalent in results if it used `count(distinct A.id)`, where `id` is unique or a primary key.

That said, although they are similar in functionality, how they are executed can be quite different.  Different SQL engines might do a better job of optimizing one version or the other.

By the way, you should avoid the archaic `join` syntax that you are using.  Since 1992, explicit joins have been part of SQL syntax.

Comment: definitely agree on the archaic join syntax. I almost thought that you had some cross products going on in which case the second query would be greatly inflated compared to the first.